# What type is in the range for loop?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector< int > v = { 1, 2, 3 };
    for ( auto it : v )
    {
        std::cout<<it<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

To what is `auto` expanding? Is it expanding to `int&` or `int`?

Comment: Historically, the auto keyword was a storage type specifier indicating an object that has automatic storage type (i.e. allocated on the stack).

Comment: @Oyeme: Sure. But how is that related to the question ?

Comment: @Oyeme:  In C++11, `auto` means something completely new.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It expands to int. If you want a reference, you can use

```
for ( auto& it : v )
{
    std::cout<<it<<std::endl;
}
```

According to the C++11 standard, `auto` counts as a *simple-type-specifier* [7.1.6.2], thus the same rules apply to it as to other *simple-type-specifiers*. This means that declaring references with `auto` is no different from anything else.

Comment: You might want to add a reference to the standard (forgive the pun) for completeness.

Comment: @JohnDibling I think you misunderstand this feature. `it` is not int because the container `v` has a certain number of elements that happens to be in the range of `int` but because `v` contains ints. If contained `SomeClass` elements, the type of `it` would be `SomeClass`.

Comment: @wilhelmtell Good suggestion, but I didn't find any explicit mention of references with the auto specifier nor with for-range-declarations (I just checked: 6.5.4 and 7.1.6.4 in the standard). I think it just comes naturally from the fact that the type is deduced and used in place of the `auto`. One could write `auto &it` as well.

Comment: `auto` uses the same type deduction algorithm of templates. If you had `template <class T> f(T t);`, `t` would be passed by value (unless the type was explicitly specified, of course), but if you had `template <class T> f(T& t);` it would be passed by reference. That's why `auto` makes it a value, while `auto&` makes it a reference.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I couldn't find mentioning of said type-deduction algorithm. However I added the most relevant part I could find. If you know a better one, feel free to edit my post or suggest it in the comments.

Answer (score 5):

I created another example, which answers the question :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct a
{
    a() { std::cout<<"constructor" << std::endl; }
    a(const a&) { std::cout<<"copy constructor" << std::endl; }
    a(a&&) { std::cout<<"move constructor" << std::endl; }

    operator int(){return 0;}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector< a > v = { a(), a(), a() };

    std::cout<<"loop start" << std::endl;
    for ( auto it : v )
    {
        std::cout<< static_cast<int>(it)<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<"loop end" << std::endl;
}
```

It is obvious that the `auto` expands to `int`, and the copy is being made. To prevent copying, the for loop needs to be with a reference :

```
for ( auto & it : v )
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. It only shows how your compiler behaves.

Comment: I think it does answer, the compiler is ought to follow the standard. Also VJo happened to submit almost the exact same answer as I did at the same moment. He deleted it and went on to provide a more complete one, so kudos for that. Mine only got that many upvotes because it was there first.