# Iteration over a vector of objects whose copy constructor has been deleted (C2280)

Tags: c++

I have a class whose copy constructor has been deleted. When attempting to iterate through a `std::vector` containing objects of this class, I can't do it the "nice" way, and have to use some sort of iteration variable.

```
struct foo {

foo() :
    val(0)
{}

foo(const foo&) = delete;

int val;

};

int main() {

std::vector<foo> fooVec(5);

for (auto f : fooVec) //C2280 - attempting to reference a deleted function!
{
    std::cout << f.val << std::endl;
}

for (int i = 0; i < fooVec.size(); i++) //no problems
{
    std::cout << fooVec[i].val << std::endl;
}

}
```

Is there a clever way of iterating over a vector of uncopyable objects that doesn't necessitate use of an iteration variable?

I'm very keen to learn how to use modern features and am trying to learn how to properly handle special member functions as part of modernising some existing code (we still have raw pointers).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What type is in the range for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269694/what-type-is-in-the-range-for-loop)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simpler than you think:

```
for (auto &f : fooVec)
```

As an extra bonus, you can modify this `f`, right where it sits in the vector, comfy in its current home. When using a basic, by-value iteration:

```
for (auto f : fooVec)
```

This makes a copy of each value in the vector (hence the problem), and any changes to `f` have no effect on the original value in the vector.

But when you iterate using a reference, no copy is made, and you can modify each value, as you iterate over it.

Or if you prefer to continue to have the compiler catch your mistakes for you:

```
for (const auto &f : fooVec)
```

This still iterates, but each referenced `f` value is `const` and not modifiable.

Comment: I see! Is this a problem of `auto` incorrectly deducing the type as a `foo` rather than a `foo&`?

Comment: No! It is not a problem of `auto`. When `auto` is deduced, it is not deduced to the reference. By design.

Comment: `auto` always deduces a non-reference type, whether it's used for a range iteration variable, or any other variable. So, to deduce a reference you have to make it one, `auto &`. Think of `auto` as being a placeholder wildcard for any ***non-reference*** type.